# MySQL find maximum date per month

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by

i have a table :

```
date         number
2018-11-01   5
2018-11-30   7
2018-10-05   3
2018-10-28   1
2018-09-01   8
2018-09-05   9
```

how to sort the value of the last day for each month ?

i try :

```
$mysqli->query("
SELECT * 
  FROM stats 
 GROUP 
    BY YEAR(date)
     , MONTH(date) desc 
 ORDER 
    BY date desc");
```

and also tryed with MAX() but without success :(

i would like to have in my while rows this result :

```
 date        number
 2018-11-30  7
 2018-10-28  1
 2018-09-05  9
```

so just keep the value(number) of the last day for each month.

Thanks !

Comment: Using `SELECT * ... GROUP BY ...` is always wrong.. [(My)SQL mistakes. Do you use GROUP BY correctly?](https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/)

Comment: What should happen which ties? Meaning WHERE max date is the same within the group.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate max date for each year-month pair and join with it:

```
SELECT date, number
FROM stats
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(date) AS maxdate
    FROM stats
    GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
) x ON stats.date = maxdate
```

Comment: Perfect ! I just add ORDER BY date desc at the end ;) Many thanks @Salman-A

Comment: Thats also pretty neat: `select YEAR(date) year, MONTH(date) month, MAX(date) max_date, number from stats group by year, month`

Comment: you have `number` in select clause but which number would it be? the `2018-11` group contains 5 and 7; MySQL is free to return any of those values.

Comment: The solution which I now finally prefer, when you need to "SELECT *" is using a subquery instead of a join, so that you don't have maxdate in each row, and your data structure is more "original":
`SELECT * FROM stats WHERE date IN (SELECT MAX(date) FROM stats GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date))`